# Is it possible to make it more readable? treemap

Tags: r, database, treemap

I just wanna know how can I make it more readable.

```
marketcap <- data.frame(Marketcap = c(641899161594, 30552518424, 271028619181, 
                                      9277626785, 3986737880, 1202315485, 
                                      6049985280, 30722840711), 
                                      id = c('Bitcoin', 'Dogecoin', 'Ethereum', 'Litecoin', 'Monero', 'Nem', 'Stellar', 'xrp'),
                                      row.names = c('Bitcoin', 'Dogecoin', 'Ethereum', 'Litecoin', 'Monero', 'Nem', 
                                      'Stellar', 'xrp')); df
#install.packages('treemap')
library(treemap)
df1 <- na.omit(marketcap[,c('id','Marketcap')])
df1$Marketcap <- as.numeric(round(df1$Marketcap, 0))
df1$formatted_market_cap = paste0(df1$id, '\n', '$', formatC(c("642","30.5","271","9.3","4","1.2","6.044","30.7"), format = "e", digits = 2))
treemap(df1, index = 'formatted_market_cap', vSize = 'Marketcap', title = 'Cryptocurrency Market Cap (bn)', fontsize.labels=c(15, 4), palette='Set3')
```

For example, Nem is looking poor
[image: Вот итог]

Comment: Maybe more pretty ^-^

Comment: I changed the code, sorry

Comment: Thanks for helping me to understand how stackoverflow question should look. Did it!